# Calling d3 functions outside of callback

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm tryng to convert a d3 example with separate csv file, to a version that use a variable instead.

So basicly, it's just replacing
`d3.csv("myfile.csv", function(error, data){})`
to
`data = d3.csvParse(myVarThatContainCsv)`

This first step works, but not the rest of the [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ca5b03a33affa4160321) :

```
[...]
d3.csv("flare.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var root = stratify(data)
        .sum(function(d) { return d.value; })
        .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });
    [...]
}
```

If I just do

```
var csv = "id,val\none,2000\ntwo,3000\nthree,4000";
data = d3.csvParse(csv);

var root = stratify(data)
      .sum(function(d) { console.log(d);return d.taille; })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.taille - a.taille; });
```

I get the error

> stratify is not a function.

So I tried

```
var csv = "id,val\none,2000\ntwo,3000\nthree,4000";
data = d3.csvParse(csv);

var root = d3.stratify(data)
      .sum(function(d) { console.log(d);return d.taille; })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.taille - a.taille; });
```

And I get the error

> d3.stratify(data).sum is not a function

Here is my bl.ocks example : https://bl.ocks.org/matthieubrunet/c7bb7f3a533f284d24c3f12cc786e06a

I suppose I'm missing a very simple step, but can't figure it...

Thanks a lot

Comment: It is `d3.stratify()(data)` but take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/ydochnzb/ your data needs to have one root in order for stratify to work. You could provide one using the parentId. Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Looking at Mike Bostock's original Block you will notice a `var stratify = d3.stratify()` assignment above the code you are working on. This  constructs a new stratify operator allowing you to call it as a function like `stratify(data)`. Hence, you need to include that statement.

Comment: You're complety right. I did kept this line of the example in my code, but after the call to stratify, which I moved to a function. Shame on me for this noob mistake !